# Complex parsing of a logfile to retrieve information from multiple lines and store in a new file in a given format

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a file continously filling with entries such as the example below.

What I want to achieve is to match on a string, store some pieces of information from that line, get more details from some line above and add it all into a new file in a given format.

The logic would be explained as something like this:

1. Make a hit on "Dispatched message to ABCD"
2. Store the date & time in a dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi:ss format, the ID (allways 64th char and 15 numbers forwards) and the MSG text (allways from 87th char)
3. Check 10 lines above for a "Event to process" line with the same ID and store visitedCID, visitedNID, vlr
4. Sew it all together as Timestamp;ID;NUM;CID;NID;VLR;MSG

There are a few helpfull rules:

- The details above matched string "Dispatched message to ABCD" is not allways a given number of lines above but must be within 10 lines above.
  This is due to the "Inputfile" is filling rapidly so the different entries are stored for many simultaneous users (IDs)
- The line to collect with same ID within 10 lines above must contain "Event to process"

Some other statics:

- The length of Timestamp is allways the same
- The ID is allways 15 numbers
- The NUM is allways 10 numbers
- visitedCID is allways 2 or 3 numbers
- visitedNIC is allways 2 or 3 numbers
- vlr can be between 5 and 15 numbers
- MSG can be anything up to 250 chars

`Inputfile Example:`

```
Thu Jul 24|11:54:58.414|I|DataDispatcher0|Got Event : [ID=240012345678901, eventId = 240012345678901115458, num=4741234567, inbound=false, homeCID=240, homeNID=01, visitedCID=522, visitedNID=01, timestamp=Thu Jul 24 11:54:58 CEST 2014,hno=null,vlr=6012345678, msc=6012345678 eventtype=I, currentCID=null, currentNID=null teleSvcInfo=null camelPhases=null serviceKey=null gprsenabled= false APNlist: null SGSN: null]|com.uws.wmsg2.DataDispatcher|processBlock|393
Thu Jul 24|11:55:06.035|I|DataDispatcher0|Got Event : [ID=240012345678901, eventId = 24001234567890111556, num=null, inbound=false, homeCID=242, homeNID=05, visitedCID=525, visitedNID=05, timestamp=Thu Jul 24 11:55:06 CEST 2014,hno=null,vlr=6012345678, msc=null eventtype=D, currentCID=null, currentNID=null teleSvcInfo=null camelPhases=null serviceKey=null gprsenabled= false APNlist: null SGSN: null]|com.uws.wmsg2.DataDispatcher|processBlock|393
Thu Jul 24|11:55:06.035|W|39|Locking [240012345678901]. No of entries [0]|com.uws.wmsg2.Lock|LockID|58
Thu Jul 24|11:55:06.036|I|24|Event to process : [ID=240012345678901, eventId = 240012345678901115458, num=4741234567, inbound=false, homeCID=242, homeNID=05, visitedCID=525, visitedNID=05, timestamp=Thu Jul 24 11:54:58 CEST 2014,hno=null,vlr=6012345678, msc=6012345678 eventtype=I, currentCID=null, currentNID=null teleSvcInfo=null camelPhases=null serviceKey=null gprsenabled= false APNlist: null SGSN: null]|com.uws.wmsg2.EventProcessor|processEvent|139
Thu Jul 24|11:55:06.041|I|35| Event for dispatching messages 240012345678901115458|com.uws.wmsg2.MSGMessageDispatcher|dispatchMessage|55
Thu Jul 24|11:55:06.072|I|35|Dispatched message to ABCD :  ID : 240012345678901, MSG : Welcome to oblivion. There will be no quarrel held. Please enjoy your stay. : ABCD3750251406.195706.62820|com.uws.wmsg2.MSGMessageDispatcher|dispatchMessage|108
Thu Jul 24|11:55:06.074|W|35|Unlocking [240012345678901]. No of entries [1]|com.uws.wmsg2.Lock|UnLockID|64
```

`Desired Output:`

```
24.07.2014 11:55:06;240012345678901;4741234567;525;05;6012345678;Welcome to oblivion. There will be no quarrel held. Please enjoy your stay.
```

I hope I was able to explain well enough. Can anybody come up with a method of achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add any attempts you've made to answer this yourself so that we can help trouble shoot?

Comment: I must admit I am short on answers. I don't even know how this would be approached. I can perhaps mangle my way through just identifying the "Dispatched message to ABCD" line and formatting that somehow sensibly, but I have no clue as to how to identify a line that exists "withing 10 lines above match" and then putting information from those two together. Sorry.

Comment: The only way to handle something like "identify a line that exists within 10 lines above match" is to keep a buffer of lines you have processed (or the processed data from it which you're interested in) so you can search that buffer. You'll have to make sure that buffer doesn't get too large either.

Comment: If I were you, I would break down the task to individual problems, and then ask a question related to a specific problem, showing some code that you've attempted. As it is, you're basically asking someone to write the code for you, which serves nobody well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this script a try;

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile=$1
newfile="dispatchclean.csv"
previous=1
current=0
if [[ -n $logfile ]]
then
    while read line; do 
    ((current++))
    #get a line of interest
    LastLineofInterest=`echo $line | grep "Dispatched message to ABCD"` 
    #if found than get other info
    if [[ -n $LastLineofInterest ]]
    then
        #get the date and convert the format to dd.mm.yyyy
        date=`echo $LastLineofInterest | awk -F'|' '{print $1}'`
        datedmY=`date -d"$date" +%d.%m.%Y`
        #get the time portion hh:mm:ss
        time=`echo $LastLineofInterest | awk -F'|' '{$0=substr($2,1,8)}1'`
        #get the string between ID and MSG
        ID=`echo $LastLineofInterest | sed -E 's/(.*ID : )(.*)(, MSG.*)/\2/'`
        #get the string between MSG and :
        MSG=`echo $LastLineofInterest | sed -E 's/(.*MSG : )(.*)( :.*)/\2/'`
        #look for the ID in the 10 lines before the actual message
        #IDinLast10l=`grep -B 10 "Dispatched message to ABCD" $logfile | grep $ID`
        IDinLast10l=`sed -n "${previous},${current}p" $logfile | grep $ID`
        #get relevant info from above string
        num=`echo $IDinLast10l | sed -E 's/(.*num=)(.*)(, inbound.*)/\2/'`
        CID=`echo $IDinLast10l | sed -E 's/(.*visitedCID=)(.*)(, visitedNID.*)/\2/'`
        NID=`echo $IDinLast10l | sed -E 's/(.*visitedNID=)(.*)(, timestamp.*)/\2/'`
        vlr=`echo $IDinLast10l | sed -E 's/(.*vlr=)(.*)(, msc.*)/\2/'`
        #append to the newfile
        echo "$datedmY $time;$ID;$num;$CID;$NID;$vlr;$MSG" >> $newfile
        previous=$current
    fi
    done < $logfile
else
    echo "please supply the logfile as parameter"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! I did run into some issues with the sed sub's for ID, MSG etc. so I ended up solving it as eg. : MSG=`echo $LastLineofInterest |grep -o -P '(?<=MSG : ).*(?=MSGREFNUM)'` which as far as I can tell is supposed to do the same thing.. Manual states . should do special chars and whatnot so I don't understand it but worked with a grep.

Comment: You're welcome. It works with "GNU sed version 4.2.1" and "GNU sed version 4.2.2", but your grep alternative also works.

Comment: I spotted another flaw. The IDinLast10l get's filled with data from lines that are much further away than 10 lines, basically seems to pick up any match from entire file. Even if there are no matches to ID above "Dispatched message to ABCD" but only after. Any idea why?

Comment: It still statically referred to dispatch.log in stead of the variable $logfile. Other than than I don't see why; do you have duplicate ID's?

Comment: Yeah, I changed that to $logfile previously. There are duplicate IDs, but not withing -B 10 criteria.

Comment: ok, so the ID is not unique. You should use an ID which is unique, maybe the eventId?

Comment: EventID only exists for the line we wish to find, and we are looking for that line based on ID from another "Dispatched.." line so that won't work. The line should exist within 10 lines above that, but the -B 10 in combination with "| grep $ID" (grep AND) doesn't seem to work properly. I will try to think of something and post back if I figure it out. Thanks again Kokkie!

Comment: Than you shouldn't use the last 10 lines of the found ID, but from last linenumber to the next linenumber where the ID in question is found, e.g. sed -n '10,20p' $logfile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58348/discussion-between-kokkie-and-andy-thompson).

Comment: The above may produce the output you want from a given sample input file but it will fail at various points and in various ways given various contents of your input file. Any time you find yourself writing a loop in shell to manipulate the contents of a text file you have the wrong approach. The UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools and the standard UNIX tool to manipulate the contents of a text file is awk.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your input a bit to isolate the problems. Given an input file like this:

```
$ cat file            
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
q r s t
u v w x
y z A B
```

Here is how to keep a buffer of the last 5 lines read, and when the letter "r" is seen print the 2nd field from the 3rd line before it:

```
$ awk '/r/{split(buf[(NR-3)%5],arr); print arr[2]} {buf[NR%5]=$0}' file
f
```

In your case you'd just change the `5` to a `10`, change the `3` to whatever preceding line(s) you want and access `arr[]` using whatever indices you like.

Now - what else do you need to do?